# Need help making a Headquarters via Equipment Advantage as portable pocket dimension?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

In the M&M3e Gamemaster's Kit the Mystic gets a Headquarters Advantage.

> Equipment 3 (Headquarters)
>   **Headquarters—Size:** Medium, Toughness: 10; Features: Concealed,
>   Dual-size (Huge), Laboratory, Library, Living Space, Personnel, Sealed,
>   Security System, Self-repairing, Workshop • 15 points

1. How do turn this or place this HQ into a pocket dimension only accessible by me?
2. How do I get there and bring guests?

Mystics do have a teleport option.

> **Teleportation:** Teleport 4 (500 feet), Accurate, Easy, Extended (16 miles), Portal

Do I just add Movement 1, Dimesion Travel to the formula or have it separate with the Extra Linked to the Teleportation Portal?

Comment: does ValhallaGH's answer work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First, Accept that no Headquarters is Impenetrable

No matter what security restrictions the Headquarters has, someone can break in with enough skill and the appropriate powers.

### Answers

1. It already has those mechanics (Sealed). You just need to define the descriptors as such.
2. By going to the address and activating the entrance. You define that, within the limits of the relevant mechanics (Concealed, Dual-Size, Sealed, and Security System) that are applied.

**Sealed**

> This is similar to the Isolated feature, except the lair is
>   sealed off from the outside world rather than isolated by
>   geographic location. It may be a structure with no doors,
>   windows, or other outside access, or behind some sort
>   of barrier. **Only the lair’s owner and designated guests
>   may enter**, although the GM should determine means by
>   which trespassers might do so, including effects like Dimensional
>   Travel, Insubstantial, Permeate, and Teleport.

Sealed is the main feature you're looking for (and already have) - putting your base in another dimension is about as "sealed off" as a base can be. Your GM may require this Feature to be taken repeatedly, or combined with another Feature, for the GM's sense of game balance.

---

One rank of Movement (Dimensional Travel) would allow the character to enter the headquarters from anywhere. Without it, the Headquarters assumes that there is a real-world entry point the character has to reach to enter the headquarters.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80008/discussion-on-answer-by-valhallagh-need-help-making-a-headquarters-via-equipment).