# Does Movement (Dimensional) allow you to choose where you go?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds-3e

This came up in an extended discussion [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80008/discussion-on-answer-by-valhallagh-need-help-making-a-headquarters-via-equipment) for [Need help making a Headquarters via Equipment Advantage as portable pocket dimension?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/126054/need-help-making-a-headquarters-via-equipment-advantage-as-portable-pocket-dimen).

> **Hey I Can Chan**: That addresses one concern, but I'm actually more interested in if the dimensional mover gets to pick where he arrives in the dimension to which he's newly traveled. That is, does he get to pick to arrive anywhere in the headquarters dimension and, likewise, anywhere in his home dimension? Also, this ability sounds like it would enable a dimensional mover who was transported to a third dimension to always have a way home (by going from dimension 3 to the HQ dimension and back to dimension 1). Is that accurate? (I'm just evaluating game balance, BTW, not, like, picking on the answer!)

**TL;DR**: Does Movement (Dimensional) allow you to choose where you go in the target dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My argument is that the answer is generally **No** on this, particularly since it has the risk of creating a very cheap Teleport power by moving to one dimension, and then moving back at another location. Furthermore, nothing in the description of the power provides that advantage.

> You can move instantly from one dimension to another as a move action. For 1 rank, you can move between your home dimension and one other. For 2 ranks you can move between any of a related group of dimensions (mystical dimensions, alien dimensions, etc). For 3 ranks you can travel to any dimension. You can carry up to 50 lbs. (mass rank 0) of additional material with you when you move. If you apply the Increased Mass modifier, you can carry additional mass up to your modifier rank.

I think the most common-sense rule for determining where a person winds up when doing dimensional travel is to simply make that decision with the GM when the power is created. The three most common setups:

- **Fixed Location** - When the transportation happens, the person always goes to the same location in the other dimension when they make the transport. This is commonly something like a gate or a summoning circle.
- **Back to where you came from** - However the location was handled the first time the person traveled, the result is that when they go back to a dimension, they go to where they left from. So if you pop out of your apartment in New York City to Faerieland, you go to the last place you were at in Faerieland. If you travel a hundred leagues to another kingdom and then head back to Earth, you're back in your apartment and the next time you head to Faerieland, you're in that distant kingdom.
- **Dimensional Rules** - There are rules determining where you go when you make the jump which may be simple or may be complex (and the character may not be fully aware of how it works). This can range anywhere from locations being tied together so that every time you transport from your apartment, you go to a particular room in an inn in Faerieland, but traveling from the top of Pyramid Plaza puts you in Aelfric's tower privy, to where it's depending on time, place, phase of the moon, what color you're wearing... it might even essentially be random. A savvy player may figure out ways to exploit this, especially if walking 50 feet in Faerieland gives them a location 500 miles away on Earth.

Note that these can be mixed and matched between destinations. It's entirely possible to have a Movement (Dimensional) power that puts you in various locations in Faerieland, but always returns you to that little henge in the park on Earth. And a valid Complication involves the rules changing for unforseen circumstances, transporting the heroes to a location they don't expect.

**But what if my player wants to choose where they go?**

In this case, I'd argue that you have them buy Flawed Teleport linked to the Movement (Dimension) power. To determine how many ranks they have to purchase, establish how dimensional travel to that world would normally work (as with the methods listed above) and then figure the distance from there.

Comment: I'm willing to consider other answers, but I do like mine, and since no one else has responded in the 48 hours, I'll accept this for now.